# Can't seem to generate an APK from ionic project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, apk

i am new to ionic, trying to get an apk for debugging i used the following commands inside the project directory:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

i did get "platforms/android" directory

and then i used:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

this is what i get after:

```
     ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
[23:57:19]  ionic-app-scripts 3.1.10
[23:57:19]  build dev started ...
[23:57:19]  clean started ...
[23:57:19]  clean finished in 10 ms
[23:57:19]  copy started ...
[23:57:19]  deeplinks started ...
[23:57:19]  deeplinks finished in 36 ms
[23:57:19]  transpile started ...
[23:57:27]  transpile finished in 8.13 s
[23:57:27]  preprocess started ...
[23:57:27]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms
[23:57:27]  webpack started ...
[23:57:28]  copy finished in 8.97 s
[23:57:35]  webpack finished in 7.63 s
[23:57:35]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[23:57:40]  sass finished in 4.83 s
[23:57:40]  postprocess started ...
[23:57:40]  postprocess finished in 28 ms
[23:57:40]  lint started ...
[23:57:40]  build dev finished in 20.79 s
[23:57:44]  lint finished in 3.91 s
> cordova build android

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Android Studio project detected
(node:12696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
    at C:\Users\h2001\Desktop\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:305:19
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\h2001\Desktop\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\h2001\Desktop\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\h2001\Desktop\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
    at C:\Users\h2001\Desktop\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:877:14
    at runSingle (C:\Users\h2001\Desktop\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\h2001\Desktop\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:12696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12696) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

but i didn't get the promised \build\outputs\apk, what is the problem?

UPDATE: i installed android studio and updated it, still getting

```
(node:12696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
```

UPDATE: the problem was solved, turns out i had java10 which wont work with android, simply installing java8 solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> btw, i dont have android sdk installed if that makes any difference?

You have answered your own question. 
To make an Android APK

- You need Java SDK 1.8.
- Android SDK with latest build tools and platforms
- JAVA_HOME & ANDROID_HOME environmental variables set correctly.

Also You need updated X-Code on a Mac to create an IPA.

Comment: i downloaded java and android sdk, still got this error:

(node:10748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: Can you paste the entire error message ?
is there no change in error message ?

Comment: (node:8236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8236) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : none

System:

   NodeJS : v8.11.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.3.0
   OS     : Windows 10

Environment:

   ANDROID_HOME : not set

Comment: @HasanAli 
Go to **Advanced System Settings** in your Windows.
Then Navigate to Environmental Variables. 
Add a new variable in system "ANDROID_HOME" and set the value as location of SDK installed.
Usually it is 
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\
Save the environmental variable.

Comment: did what u suggested, still same results!

Comment: Did you open Android Studio atleast once ?

Comment: i opened it, and updated the files, but i didn't make a new project or anything

Comment: output of ionic info again.
Also, remove the platform android using
`ionic cordova platform rm android` and add platform again

Answer (score 0):

You probably doesn't have android environment variable in your PC.
if you are running MAC try running:

```
sudo export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-macosx
sudo export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

If you are running Linux then:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

And if you are running Windows then open your command prompt as Administrator and run:

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\<installation location>\android-sdk-windows
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

It will add enviroment variable to your system.